# Flutter Cloud Firestore whereIn clause

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I try to get some lists from cloud firestore with this code

```
final User user = UserUtils.currentUser(context);

final List<String> memberLists = user.memberLists.toList();
final List<String> ownedLists = user.ownedLists.toList();
final List<String> visibleListsIds = memberLists + ownedLists;

final Query query = (sharedCollection.where(FIELD_LIST_ID, whereIn: visibleListsIds));

log.d("queryPath: ${query.reference().path}");
log.d("buildArguments: ${query.buildArguments()}");

return query.snapshots().map((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      return querySnapshot.documents
          .map(
            (document) {
              log.d("document: ${document.documentID}");
              return _getSerializers()
                  .deserializeWith(WishList.serializer, document.data);
            },
          )
          .where((value) => value != null)
          .toList();
    });
```

When I do that I do not get any logs with "document: ..." because obviously the query does not get the documents. Here are the buildArguments of the query:
`buildArguments: {where: [[listId, in, [IIAY56KF0mSCx1WwCXaV]]], orderBy: [], path: WISHLISTS}`

Note: Wishlists is the correct path and the listId is also correct.

If I change the query line to: `final Query query = sharedCollection;` it just spits out all lists, so it should work in theory. I think there is some issue with the `whereIn` operator. 
 Does anyone have a clue why this is not working? I am happy for any help.

Comment: By the way, `query.buildArguments()` is deprecated and replaced with `query.paramaters`.

Answer (score 1):

The `whereIn` operator uses the same query documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any), and is limited to 10 equality clauses. A workaround here is to split the List `visibleListsIds` to smaller chunks, similar to what have been mentioned on this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64574629/2497859).