# How to use WhereIn in flutter with firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In an ecommerce flutter app project I am using the `shortInfo` field of my items collection as an unique id for each product. When add to cart is pressed it saves the `shortInfo` to an array field called `userCartList` at my `users` collection and I am using WhereIn to query this array but when I have more than 10 product my app crashes. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my firestore structure:

[Users Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iH6pJ.png)

[Items Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfpJ8.pngstrong)

Here is a snippet of the query I am making:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>( 
    stream: EcommerceApp.firestore
                        .collection("items")
                        .where("shortInfo", whereIn: EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences.getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList))
                        .snapshots()
)
```

Comment: Could you provide the snippets of the code that are causing the error?

Comment: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            //TODO: to fix the issue
            stream: EcommerceApp.firestore
                .collection("items")
                .where("shortInfo",
                    whereIn: EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences
                        .getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList))
                .snapshots(),

Comment: This code is giving the required result but when more than 10 products are added according to the firebase rule this query mothod dosen't allow more then 10 that's what is causing the error.  User cart list is the list saved on shared Preferences that i am retrieving from firebase

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that Firestore does not allow you to make an array membership query with more that 10 records. If you check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) you will see that:

> Use the `in` operator to combine up to 10 equality (==) clauses on the same field with a logical OR

Behind the scenes your `whereIn` operator is making the same query showed in the example in the documentation and if you use more than 10 records, Firestore will not accept it and you will get an error. I suggest that you break the `EcommerceApp.userCartList` array into multiple arrays with a max of 10 records to make the query, this will allow Firestore to operate the `whereIn` within it's limits and it will work.

Let me know if you have any more questions on this matter.

Comment: I was able to fix this issue with the following code:    for (int i = 1;
              i <
                  EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences
                      .getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList)
                      .length;
              i++)
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: EcommerceApp.firestore
                  .collection("items")
                  .where("shortInfo",
                      isEqualTo: EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences
                          .getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList)[i])
                  .snapshots(),